# PHP Open SSL Decrypt Failing Inconsistently

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

I'm having some weird behaviour with the `openssl_decrypt` method in PHP. It's failing, giving me an error: `Unknown cipher algorithm`, but only *sometimes* (about 6:10 times) i.e. If I run the command enough times, it will eventually work... My code is:

`$result = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($hash), 'AES-128-CBC', $timestamp);`

running `openssl list-cipher-commands` lists AES-128-CBC as one of the available cipher methods. The specs don't really list anything on the subject - only specifying that `unknown cipher algorithm` is a possible exception from running the command.

edit:
Using the command line: i.e. running `echo "soemthing" | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc` on a random machine and then decrypting on the machine that fails with the above `echo "..." | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -d` works consistently.

Comment: That is weird. Have you tried using a lower case cipher name?

Comment: Yeah, that's what it was originally - and I was confused because the lower-case version showed up in `openssl_get_cipher_methods()`. I changed it to the uppercase version, and it worked - then start misbehaving again - so I "fixed" a non-issue.

Comment: Is it possible that you use two different PHP installations?

Comment: yes, 5.5.27 vs. 5.5.9-1

Comment: Have you checked that both have OpenSSL installed, enabled and provide that algorithm?

Comment: Yessir, and see my edit.

Comment: I can't parse that: *"then decrypting on the machine that fails with the above `echo "..." | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -d` works consistently."* Does it work or does it fail?

Comment: The machine that throws the `Unknown cipher algorithm` works when decrypting via the command line.

Comment: PHP's openssl extension is independent of the openssl commandline utility. The openssl support is compiled into PHP and may be enabled through php.ini.

Comment: Yes it is enabled and is the same as the system version 1.0.1e.